# Does a little failure in mental celibacy completely break my brahmacharya

Tags: practice, brahmacharya

Let's take a scenario in which I had practiced brahmacharya for about 1 year or so...
Now if I involuntarily got attracted mentally by a girl..and I praised her beauty. But immediately felt wrong and held back myself from that thoughts
Does that break my brahmacharya??
Will my one year of hard work go in vain??

Comment: You simply mentally praised her beauty? Or you actually said that to her?

Comment: Mentally praised her beauty

Comment: Are u looking for personal opinions as answers like the one u've selected? Or looking for something else like what Hindu scriptures have to say?

Comment: Hindu scriptures

Comment: the mind will try and use this as an excuse for you to break your physical brahmacharya. The one year is not in vain. When a child is learning to walk, he may fall down sometimes. Does the child stop trying to walk? Without a few mental falls, one cannot learn to walk or later to run. When you fall down, stand back up, brush yourself off, and try again. The only one that fails is the one that gives up and does not try again. Do not dwell on failure.

Comment: I know one yogi who carried hot chilis with him when he was starting. Whenever his mind would start to stray to sexual thoughts, he would put the hot chilis in his mouth. When he did this he could think of nothing else but the hotness in his mouth. His mind learned to not stray to those thoughts. Your mind is like a wild horse that needs to be broken and trained.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda This is a great analogy. On a related note, when I catch myself having a thought I don't want, I laugh at it. I discovered that feeling guilty about a mistake only reinforces the ego and keeps my mind on the thought. But when you laugh it off as a mistake, you can stop having the thought and move on immediately. This is related because when you see an infant fall, if the mother gasps or elseways emotes in fear the child will start crying. But, if the mother laughs off the mistake, the child will laugh, too—and then get back up and keep going.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See, this is from my own experience of Sadhana I am talking. Do not try to control over your thought process about this worldly affairs. Until you realize supreme, when senses come in contact with objects they like, when mind's attractive things you encounter, these thoughts bound to rise. So do not worry about these thoughts arising in mind. As long as anything is restricted to just thoughts, it's fine because we're in Kaliyuga, and the culture, the way we dress up, everything has changed. So you are not to be blamed.

Your focus should be on God-realization. And be focused on things which will make you realize God, and just keep moving in that direction. That will gradually release you from all bondages. When you do that, automatically negative forces which block God realization leaves. Move on what is essential, automatically non-essential leaves you. That's why in Tamil they say"ஸ்ரீ தேவி வீடு வாசலில் வந்தா, முதேவி பின்வாசல் வழியாக போய்டும்." - Focus on what you need to do in life, rest of the things will automatically fall in place

Comment: This question is more of a curiosity kind.. brahmacharya rules state that we should not touch women.. so should I not touch my sister or Mother?

Comment: What is your goal actually in this life? first say. I can help you from my experience! BTW are you in brahmacharya now?

Comment: I'm not in brahmacharya right now... I want to be one from now on .. I am confused by various sources that's why I am asking in forums about the doubts which Google couldn't answer!!  Help me please If u can

Comment: If then, fine. I'll tell you! Do not stress yourself by trying to be living too tight because in this Kaliyuga it's just extremely difficult. Your body, mind are not programmed in such a way from your childhood. So to attain God-realiziation, just make it a point to worship him with love, and meditate on him daily, and do your duties without attachment to results, and with respect to women, if it's your Mother, sister-related to blood relation, you can touch. Nothing wrong.

Comment: Even if you appreciate a beauty of another girl or women, it's fine because it's natural. But what am saying is once you reach the next step on the door to God, these kind of thoughts automatically goes away.

Comment: One more help brother.. can you state the rules of brahmacharya I need to follow?

Comment: After a period of Sadhana, if you have improved, the way you see life itself will change. That's why coming to terms with practical experience is important especially with related to God topic than speculation on Vedas puranas. Speculations won't grant us Moksha, but only by leading a life practically for God will take us to his eternal abode!

Comment: Including Brahmacharya, what are the things if we follow we can get moksha. See Uddhava Gita, follow this. It's bit simpler to follow. http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Uddhava_Gita.pdf
Chapters 6, 11, 14 is what you need to first look at!

Comment: You should cite some sources. (personal experience are not considered enough to reply on)

Comment: @user10083325 Adding this two years later: no, you cannot even touch your sister, daughter or mother if you are Brahmachaari, it is considered a breaking of the vow. Srauta Brahmins of South India (Nambudiris chiefly) consider it inauspicious to even SEE a woman (even if she is a direct relative).

Answer (score 8):

According to the Daksha Smriti (DS) sexual intercourse can be of eight kinds.

See the following verses:

> [A Yogin} should always preserve his Brahmacharyya [celibacy]; Sexual
>   intercourse is of eight sorts : -viz: **thinking of a woman**,
>   talking [about it]
>   -dalliance with a woman, looking [at a woman with an impure desire] speaking to her secretly, determination [for holding a sexual
>   congress], persistent endeavour [for doing it] and the actual deed.
>   **The learned hold that these are the eight divisions of sexual
>   intercourse.**
>
> **DS 7-32,33**

Any of these eight acts are considered as against celibacy.

So, even thinking about a woman is in violation of celibacy. But IMO, it is here talking about thinking sexually about a woman (i.e having amorous thoughts about a lady) and not about just thinking.

In your case, you simply praised her beauty in mind but did not have sexual thoughts about her.

So, IMO, **your celibacy vow is still intact.**

Comment: So technically in Kali Yuga even overall Dharmic people have committed sexual intercourse (as per DS, not the modern sense). By Dharmic here I mean those who are righteous in their conduct and behaviour, in short, good people.

Comment: But does his hinder spiritual progression a great deal? You must have guessed why I am asking this.

Comment: Yes it does probably but those verses are specifically meant for Yogis and Sannyasis.. that has to be taken into account too. @ArkaprabhaMajumdar

Comment: So basically its for the sannyasis who suffer the fall, like Kandu, Vishwamitra or Jaimini, who have been enticed by apsaras before.

Comment: Yes and the verses also apply to the persons who have ceremoniously taken celibacy vows. @ArkaprabhaMajumdar It is a problem for them if the vow is broken.